# javascript/ajax works on localhost but not on live server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, server, filesystems

If you save this code to `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pdfFilesDirectory = './uploads/pdf/';
console.log("1");
// get auto-generated page 
$.ajax({url: pdfFilesDirectory}).then(function(html) {
    console.log("2");

    // create temporary DOM element
    var document = $(html);
    console.log("3");

    // find all links ending with .pdf 
    document.find('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
        console.log("4");

        var pdfName = $(this).text();
        var pdfUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        // do what you want here 
        console.log(pdfName);
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

in the same directory create a folder `uploads/pdf/` and put two PDFs inside, start a localhost server (`python3 -m http.server` ) and open `localhost:8000`, check the console log and it should print something like:

> 1 2 3 file1.pdf file2.pdf

Navigate to `https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/` where this code is running remotely, and check the console, and there is a 404 error, or nothing, but either way the files are not being printed.

It could be an error with the URL of the files and i have tried adding file:// with the absolute path to the file.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ... Any suggestions or things i can try?